# Nativescript (Windows): tns platform add android hangs trying to extract fsevents package

Tags: android, nativescript, npm-install

When I run `tns platform add android` on Windows 10 it gets to the part where it is installing tns-android, and then hangs trying to extract the fsevents package.

It looks like the solution would be to run `npm install` with the `--no-optional` flag. I tried `tns platform add android --no-optional` but this doesn't work.

Comment: Check these comments suggesting a possible solution https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/3019#issuecomment-319493730

Comment: I'm using npm v6.2.0

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve this for now by downgrading npm to v5.10.0